# C# Trying to type cast array values

Tags: c#, tryparse

When trying to cast an int from an array string value in the following code;

```
   using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;


    namespace hourscount
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                string delimiter = ":";
                string time1 = Console.ReadLine();
                string time2 = Console.ReadLine();

                if (time1 == null || time2 == null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Program expects two values!");
                    Console.ReadLine();

                }
                else
                {
                    string[] time1var = time1.Split(new string[] {delimiter}, StringSplitOptions.None);
                    string[] time2var = time2.Split(new string[] { delimiter }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                    int time2Intvar1 = int.TryParse(time2var[0]);
                    int time1Intvar1 = int.TryParse(time1var[0]);
                    int time2Intvar2 = int.TryParse(time2var[1]);
                    int time1Intvar2 = int.TryParse(time1var[1]);
                    int realHours = (time2Intvar1 - time1Intvar1);
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

I am getting the following error; Error 1 No overload for method 'TryParse' takes 1 argument

Comment: This isn't a cast, it's parsing and/or a conversion. And with Intellisense, why isn't it apparent to you that an additional argument is required? I don't quite get that.

Comment: I thought timeXvar[X] was the argument.

Comment: **Additional** argument.

Comment: Show me where you see the word Additional

Comment: It's in my first comment to your question, plain as day. Is this the same reason you missed the information about this argument in Intellisense?

Comment: I don't give a shit about your comment numnutz. Where in the error message does it say the word additional?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use it as

```
int time2Intvar1;
bool isOK = int.TryParse(time2var[0],out time2Intvar1);
```

For more information see

http://www.dotnetperls.com/int-tryparse

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx

Answer (score 4):

You need to provide the [`out` parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee332485.aspx) for [`int.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1):

```
int time2Intvar1;
bool canBeParsed = int.TryParse(time2var[0], out time2Intvar1);
```

It is initalized afterwards.